# How to extract the unit and subunit parts from the given amount of money represented in microunits?

Tags: java, regex, currency, rounding-error

I'm working on project in Java and have a price in micro-units.

A price in micro-units is a price, where 1,000,000 micro-units equal one unit of the currency. For example, if price is "€7.99", price_amount_micros is "7990000"

I need to extract 7 and 99 as separate strings. Having read some posts about rounding errors, I think the right way to achieve what I need is to convert the given amount to a string and extract the unit and subunit parts using the following regex:

```
^(\d+)(\d{2})0000$
```

However, for some reason, I feel like it's not an elegant way.

Comment: I don't think you can have rounding errors since all that you need is to divide by 10^n and to apply a floor function.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, if you gave a more detailed answer with proof, I might even accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refine it to:

```
^(\d+)(\d{2})0{4}$
```

But then you are done imho.

I handle all Prices as INT in my Databases.
7.99 would be 799 there. 
There are no Rounding-Errors.

Answer (score 1):

It may look like an overkill but to be on safer side with floating point issues, you can use `BigDecimal` based logic as this:

```
void extractParts(String str) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(str);        
    BigDecimal res = bd.scaleByPowerOfTen(-6);
    BigDecimal rem = res.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).stripTrailingZeros();

    System.out.printf("<%s> <%s>%n", res.longValue(), 
          rem.movePointRight(rem.scale()).abs().longValue());
}
```

Then call it as:

```
extractParts("7990000");
//=> <7> <99>

extractParts("-1835000");
//=> <-1> <835>

extractParts("89000000");
//=> <89> <0>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 83.5? It should be 83.5 cents not 835 cents.

Comment: What input string are you sending to this method?

Comment: Amazing convert, thank you :)